# Open source plugin for share links like Addthis?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use something like Addthis on my website, but I want to keep my traffic data private.

Is there any jquery/PHP way that I can use to put many share buttons on my site at once like AddThis without external tracking?

Comment: What's wrong with simple images and anchor tags?  There isn't anything complex about it.

Comment: You mean get the code from all the sites individually for each site?  AddThis has hundreds of things you can share to and that would take a very long time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://frankkoehl.com/2009/03/free-open-source-alternative-sharethis-addthis-addtoany/

The tl;dr version is that there is an opensource alternative (called [iBegin Share](http://www.enthropia.com/labs/share/)). It is under an MIT license which gives you the right to:

> deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
>   the rights to use, copy, **modify**...

Comment: Last release in 2012? How about social count plus? https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-count-plus/description/